# Incorrect endpoint firing using Route attribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following methods in my UserController. The first two, `Register` and `VerifyUser` work fine.

However - I can't get login to be called. No matter what combination of URLs I try - the `Register` method fires.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Register")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Register([FromBody]RegisterUserModel model)
    {
        ....
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{email}/{verifyId}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage VerifyUser(string email, string verifyId)
    {
        ....
    }

    [Route("Login")] //Not being fired - Register being fired
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody]RegisterUserModel userMod)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe it falls into VerifyUser when trying to find the correct route?

Comment: The `Register` route is being called when I want `Login`

Comment: @Tomcelic what are the urls being called. also check to make sure attribute routing is enabled in `WebApiConfig` ie `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you most likely have the default convention based route only

```
// Convention-based routing.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

which would map to register first and not bother to check `Login`.

calling `api/user/Login` would map to the `api/{controller}/{id}` convention route with `Login` being mapped to the `id` placeholder. The route table to use the HTTP verb POST to find the first action that could handle a post with the provided body. It would find register first and map to that action.

Check to make sure attribute routing is enabled in `WebApiConfig` ie

```
// Attribute routing.
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

// Convention-based routing.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The comments in the following shows the Url that maps to the actions.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController {

    //Matches POST api/user/register
    [Route("Register")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Register([FromBody]RegisterUserModel model) {
        //....
    }

    //Matches GET api/user/some_email/some_id
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{email}/{verifyId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult VerifyUser(string email, string verifyId) {
        //....
    }

    //Matches POST api/user/login
    [Route("Login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody]RegisterUserModel userMod) {
        //....
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)